# Is it possible to see sharks when diving in Belongas Bay, Lombok in December?

Tags: indonesia, nature-and-wildlife, diving, lombok

I will be in Lombok, Indonesia, in December 2016. Because I'm a diver, I would like to know about underwater life, mostly hammerhead shark. Is there possibility to see sharks there in December?

Comment: @pnuts but then it's too late to help the OP ;)

Answer (score 2):

With climate being as changeable as it has been recently it seems that almost anything likely in one season may be *possible* in another, however the best indication I could find is that December is **not** a good choice for hammerhead shark spotting in Lombok. Mainly based on:

> the best site being 'The Magnet' where schools of hammerheads frequent from the end of June until the first week of November

from [Divescover](http://diving-hammerheads.divescover.com/).